# Loading discriminated unions from a database

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have a discriminated union defined like this:

```
enum ShapeKind {
  Square = 'sqaure',
  Rectangle = 'rectangle',
}

interface Square {
    kind: ShapeKind.Square;
    size: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
    kind: ShapeKind.Rectangle;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle;
```

I want to be able to load them from the database. I have a method with the following signature:

```
getShape(kind: ShapeKind, id: string): Shape
```

This performs a database query as follows, and returns an object matching the interface based on the `kind` field of the record:

```
SELECT * FROM shapes WHERE id = ? AND kind = ? LIMIT 1
```

If I pass in `ShapeKind.Rectangle` I know it must return a `Rectangle` (or throw a not found error), but at the moment the return type is always `Shape` regardless of what I pass in.

How do I make the compiler understand this rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function getShape(kind: ShapeKind.Rectangle, id: string): Rectangle
function getShape(kind: ShapeKind.Square, id: string): Square
function getShape(kind: ShapeKind, id: string): Shape {
  // Your query here  
  switch (kind) {
    case ShapeKind.Rectangle:
      return {
        kind: ShapeKind.Rectangle,
        width: 1,
        height: 1,
      }
    case ShapeKind.Square:
      return {
        kind: ShapeKind.Square,
        size: 1,
      }
  }
}
```